# How reliable is this way of sorting arrays of objects by multiple properties?

Tags: javascript

I need to sort an array of object literals and I need to compare 2 of the object's properties. I found an example online of how to do it but I couldn't find any supporting documentation in the spec. Can anyone confirm that you can do the following in Javascript and possibly point me to some documentation:

```
users.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return [a.name, a.company] > [b.name, b.company] ? 1:-1; 
});
```

Edit: I now get why this is working, it's because it's simply concatenating and then comparing the strings. I don't think the intention is very clear so I'll probably write something a little less hacky.

Also, I wasn't simply asking if you could create a custom sort function, that you can easily find in the docs. I was asking if the way I was doing it in this particular case is valid.

Comment: You could do that, but it seems to be a bit hacky. You are basically comparing the concatenation of `x.name` and `x.company` with each other. I.e. it's the same as `a.name + ',' + a.company > b.name + ',' + b.company`.

Comment: @Felix - why is that hacky?  Seems genius to me.  Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I'd do an explicit concatenation (someone *could* overrite Array.prototype.toString) or be do it in multiple steps and test name and then (only if the names were equal) the company. Code that is obvious about how it works is good for maintainers to maintain.

Comment: @Adam: If you know how it works, yes. But it seems to suggest that JavaScript compares the single elements in an array, which is not like that. That's just my personal opinion though.

Comment: @Felix - it took me a minute looking at it - at first I thought it was invalid, but then I realized that the array would implicitly convert to string.  Then I thought it was genius.  I guess it's one of those questions of how low of a common denominator do you have to code for.

Comment: @Adam: In addition, it may fail if any value is a number, since it is performing a lexicographical(?) comparison, not a numerical comparison. Example: `[100] > [11]` is `false`.

Comment: @Felix I wish you would have made this a comment so I could mark this as the answer.

Comment: Was just writing an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already explained in the comments, yes, you *could* do it like that.

**What is happening here?**

Whenever you use arrays in a comparison, the array is converted to its *string representation*, which is simply a comma delimited list of its elements. JavaScript is **not** comparing each element of the array individually.

So in your example, you are concatenating `a.name` with `a.company` and `b.name` with `b.company` and compare this concatenation:

```
"nameA,companyA" > "nameB,companyB"
```

**What is the catch?**

You will have problems though if any of these values is a number (not a string), since the lexicographical order of numbers is different than their numerical order.

For example:

```
> ['a', 100] > ['a', 11]
  false
```

You end up comparing `'a,100'` against `'a,11'`, and since `0` comes before `1`, the first string is smaller than second one.

---

The bottom line is: If you know that you are only dealing with string values, you are probably fine, though the implicit concatenation can be difficult to comprehend.
Once you have mixed data types, you really should compare the values individually.

Answer (score 3):

You can.

- [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (generally the best developer friendly reference online)
- [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (section 15.4.4.11) (the official standard)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the `sort` functionality, you can refer to `Mozilla Developer Network` for a reference.

**Reference**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

It basically allows you to define a callback function for which `sort` may be implemented. Why does this sort function work in particular? Try this simplified example:

```
foo = [1, 2]
[1, 2]
bar = [3, 4]
[3, 4]
foo > bar
>> false
bar > foo
>> true
```

By comparing the string representation of the arrays, Javascript may evaluate the value of an array as a result.

Comment: JavaScript is not comparing the individual elements of the array, it is comparing the array's string representations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's valid.
Here's the MDN [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `Array.sort` is a function that takes a `cmp` argument, which is itself a function that takes two arguments to compare:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort